# Best Approach to Receive Email of a particular account under asp.net core

Tags: .net-core, twilio-api, mailkit, sendgrid-api-v3

We need to setup a mechanism of  receiving email of a particular **Account** of a **Domain**, Just like normal ticketing system reply emails.

Found some of the sources of how it could be achieved.

**Either Go For Custom Solution**

https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit

https://joshwright.com/tips/tips-sending-receiving-email-in-csharp/

**Send Grid Web Hooks**

The Other Ready to go solution is Send Grid, but the problem with send grid is it monitors each and every email of domain, i can filter them at my end but still it  doesn't seem good approach keeping the security prospect in mind.
Here our Approach could be , can create a sub domain under the domain and receive those emails

I am currently using send grid for sending emails

Looking forward , what could the best, reliable and scalable approach and the pros and corns of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply write a C# program to receive emails of that particular box as follows:

```
var client = new POPClient();
client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, true);
client.Authenticate("admin@bendytree.com", "YourPasswordHere");

var count = client.GetMessageCount();

// use a for loop to get the subject / message
Message message = client.GetMessage(count);

Console.WriteLine(message.Headers.Subject);

// message.Headers.From.Address; 
// from address
// messagePart.BodyEncoding.GetString(messagePart.Body);
// message body
```

**modify the above program** so that, after receiving the email, the system

1. inject the subject and message into a db record
2. generate a ticket number
3. reply to the sender that a ticket (# xxxxxx) has been issued
4. follow up all the correspondence using this ticket (store all the correspondence in the db record)

Comment: using third party like mailkit gives other options as saving attachemnts with knowing the CC and other stuff, what are your thoughts on it

Comment: yes you may always use third party solutions like mailkit. But third party programs will not allow unrestricted modifications like the points in 1 , 2, 3 and 4 above. On the other hand, using Csharp for sure allows you to send cc and manage attachments, etc.